# Nested queries and double negation

Tags: sql, oracle

the question is 'Find publishers that have released books on all fields.'

```
book(ISBN(PK), Publisher(FK))
field(Book(FK), field)
Publisher(name(PK))
```

i havent been able to find out exactly what to do, and have been trying different ways but to no help. i asked about it but the answer was...not the best. The answer i was given was- the logic is to be 'find publisher where there isnt a field that the publisher hasnt published a book about'-

Comment: This schema is wonky... Why does the `Field` table have a `FOREIGN KEY` relation to `Book`?  This doesn't make any sense.  With the structure that you've provided, how would you determine what *all fields* actually means?  The logic you mentioned is correct, you need to do check for the non-existence of a field that an author hasn't published a book in. *(Hint: You'll likely need a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` or an `OUTER JOIN`.)*

Answer (score 0):

```
with cnt as (select count(distinct field) c from field)
select b.Publisher 
  from book b 
  inner join field f on (b.ISBN=f.Book) 
  inner join cnt on (1=1) 
group by b.Publisher, cnt.c 
having count(distinct field) = cnt.c;
```

I believe this will work.

Comment: The count in the `HAVING` clause should be on `field` rather than `publisher`, right?

Comment: @mathguy Yes, I've amended that.